# A conjecture on the prime counting function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I was thinking about the Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for quite sometime (some of my posts are related to this). In one of my [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959502/partial-proof-of-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture-modified) I conjectured that the inequality ($\pi(x)$ denotes the prime counting function), $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)>2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$$ is true. However, R. Israel showed that this inequality falls infinitely often. Basing upon the counter example that he gave I put forward the following two conjectures,

> **Conjecture 1** $\pi(x)+\pi(y)\le2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$ for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$.

It seems that the former conjecture is true if the quantity $\dfrac{x}{y}$ be sufficiently large (assume $x\ge y$).

So my question is that,

> Is there any proof of **Conjecture 1**?

Assuming there is no such proof at present can anyone suggest me some relevant literature which shed some light on proving this conjecture?

Comment: If you think about how such a conjecture could fail, you could imagine a dense constellation of primes between x and (x+y)/2 and very few primes between (x+y)/2 and y  In fact, it is likely that both conjectures fail infinitely often, and conjecture 2 certainly fails for x=y.  You might consider running a computer program to check your conjecture for a few million pairs (x,y), to see how it fails.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Prime Gaps" Paseman, 2015.06.30

Comment: I think that I was too occupied regarding the truth of the conjecture. well, thanks for your suggestion, I will surely try that when I get some time. However, it would be great to have some literature regarding this conjecture.

Comment: It might be great, but it is unlikely.  There might be more refined versions of the conjecture in connection with Goldbach's binary conjecture.  However, primes fluctuate wildly enough that I would only expect either relation to hold with x and y separated by a significant power of x.  For a start, check out texts by Hans Riesel and by Paulo Ribenboim on primes.  That and much experimentation may give you a feel for plausible conjectures on distribution of primes.  Gerhard "Feels His Way Around Primes" Paseman, 2015.06.30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for a large gap in the distribution of primes.  For this conjecture, the gap between $n!+2$ and $n!+n$ will suffice.  Set $y = n!+2$ (which is composite) and set $m$ (which will be $\frac{x+y}{2}$, so $x$ will be $2m-y$ eventually) to be the largest composite so that there are no primes between $m$ and $y$.  Then there will be primes between $x$ and $m$ and none between $m$ and $y$.

So $\pi(x) + \pi(y) = \pi(x) + \pi\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) > 2 \pi\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$.  So your conjecture will fail for infinitely many pairs $x$ and $y$.

Gerhard "This Belongs On Another Forum" Paseman, 2015.06.30

Comment: Note that if you allow y to be prime, you can extend the argument above to any gap. Put another way, for any prime (and also for any composite) y there is an x such that conjecture 1 fails for  that x and y, and x will often differ from y by at most a constant times log y .